# Angular4 gets 404 after refresh when using Path Location Strategy on server

Tags: angularjs, angular

I'm facing a problem in the urls in angular4 :

get on the serve

> Not Found The requested URL /profile/home was not found on this
>   server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

My app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy, PathLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

import { ImageUploadModule } from 'angular2-image-upload';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AddComponent } from './add/add.component';
import { EditComponent } from './edit/edit.component';
import { ProfileService } from './services/profile.service'
import { MessageService } from './services/message.service'


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    AddComponent,
    EditComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ImageUploadModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  providers: [ProfileService, MessageService,{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy}],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Have you tried to replace HashLocationStrategy with PathLocationStrategy?

Comment: yes,i've tried replace HashLocationStrategy with PathLocationStrategy